# Median of limiting distribution is the limit of medians when $X_n\overset{d}{\rightarrow}X$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of random variables with
> medians $\eta_1, \eta_2,\ldots$ such that
>
> $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \eta_n = \eta$$
>
> Show that if $X_n\overset{d}{\rightarrow}X$, then $\eta$ is the median
> of $X$.

**My try:**

Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \eta_n = \eta$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} F_{X_n}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \eta$

Since $X_n\overset{d}{\rightarrow}X$ then

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}F_{X_n}(t)=F_X(t)$$

for all $t$ at which $F$ is continuous. It follows that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}F^{-1}_{X_n}(t)=F^{-1}_X(t)$$

for all $t$ at which $F$ is continuous (I think this might be too strong of an assumption).

Hence $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}F^{-1}_{X_n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=F^{-1}_X\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and so $F^{-1}_X\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\eta$.

I have my doubts on if this is right. Is there a different approach I should take?